# Bluetooth audio has background noise

Tags: 14.04, sound, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth headphone (Bluedio T) connected to my desktop. The audio works fine in A2DP mode, I am quite happy with the audio quality. However, there is a constant background noise, a quiet sizzle sound any time something is played, and for a few second afterwards. E.g., if I play the test sounds in the sound settings, sizzling starts, she says "front left", and then sizzling continues for 2 seconds. This is why I do not think it is a badly transmitted audio signal. So far I have tried tuning in alsamixer (microphone boost), did not work,  and tested the headphones on other devices (works as expected, no noise). Do you have any hints what may cause this?

Comment: Open the mixer and verify there is no audio source enabled, it could be your microphone or something like that.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I don't know what you mean exactly my mixer, but under sound settings/inputs, only my headphone's microphone is listed, and that is muted.